# Custom control, View Model and dependency properties

Tags: silverlight, xaml, mvvm

I'm creating custom control and because I need to do lot's of binding inside a style/template it makes perfect sense to go with MVVM. Where do I declare dependency properties then?

Do they stay in control class? How do I link them to VM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [my answer to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8003466/viewmodel-have-to-be-public-how-should-i-deal-with-that/8004000#8004000) about custom controls and view models.  Here's the short version:

1. Custom controls shouldn't have view models.
2. Don't set the data context of your own control. That's reserved for the consumer.
3. All of your dependency properties should be declared in your MyCustomControl.cs file.
4. Use TemplateBinding in your genric.xaml because it's more efficient that Binding.

To put it another way, what's the view model for a Border or a Button? Answer: they don't have one because they're just controls. UserControls have view models, but controls just present and interact with the data which you give them (where? In your UserControl). Custom control development is probably the hardest thing for a seasoned MVVM developer: your reflex is to make a view model, but that reflex is unfortunately wrong. I know because I've made this mistake myself.

Answer (score 1):

Dependency Properties could be delared in the Control they are belongs to.

When following MVVM in WPF/Silverlight the common approach is to set ViewModel as DataContext of the appropriate View. So you would be able to link custom Dependency Properties to the ViewModel properties using Bindings in XAML.

Let's assume you already set ViewMosel to DataContext of the View:

```cs
var view = new UserView 
               { 
                 DataContext = new UserViewModel { Name = "Custom Name" } 
               };

public class UserViewModel
{
   string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**UserView.xaml:**

```xml
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
```

Comment: This is how you do with a usercontrol, not custom control

Comment: @Xin: really as far as I remember I've used custom controls without template bindings approach, but directly specifying bindings in  View.Xaml, like `<MyCustomControl ItemsSource="{...}" MyCustomControl.CustomProperty="..." / >` so this is should not be a problem

Answer (score 0):

When creating a custom control, the control itself is a view model. Declare dependency properties on it to expose bindings that users of the custom control can leverage. For example if you have a timeline control, you might have properties like StartDate and EndDate on the control exposed as dependency properties. Your Controls Default Template would make template bindings to the dependency properties. A consumer of your control might then have a project timeline viewmodel that he binds to the properties on the control.

The primary purpose of a custom control is to provide behavior and a default look and feel for that behavior which is easy to override (by providing a new template). Hope this helps.